# How to add vue-tailwind-datepicker to Laravel Vue Inertia project?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a Laravel 10.x project using Vue.js and Inertia.
I would like to add and use [Vue Tailwind Datepicker](https://github.com/elreco/vue-tailwind-datepicker) component.
For this, I tried to follow and adapt [this tutorial](https://dev.to/elreco/add-a-tailwind-datepicker-to-your-vue-3-application-57j2) to my case. Here is what I did:

- I run `npm install -D @tailwindcss/forms` and I found this pluging is automatically added into **tailwind.config.js** in the plugins array (`plugins: [forms]`)
- I run `npm i dayjs`
- I then installed the package in question: `npm install vue-tailwind-datepicker`
- In **resources/js/app.js** I added this line: `import VueTailwindDatepicker from 'vue-tailwind-datepicker';` and updateded like this: `.component('VueTailwindDatepicker', VueTailwindDatepicker)`

Then I tried to use the datepicker component like this:

```
<script setup>
import VueTailwindDatepicker from "vue-tailwind-datepicker";

const dateValue = ref([]);
const formatter = ref({
  date: "DD MMM YYYY",
  month: "MMM",
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
     <vue-tailwind-datepicker :formatter="formatter" v-model="dateValue" />
  </div>
</template>
```

But the input field is not interacting, I just get this:

[image]

No errors shown anywhere.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first attempt can be seen in the edit history of my question:

```
// In resources/js/app.js
use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy, VueTailwindDatepicker)
```

But I had to write:

```
.component('VueTailwindDatepicker', VueTailwindDatepicker)
```

This is what I wrote when I edited my question, but I forgot to run `npm run watch` so the changes were not reflected.